# Getting the name from an R class in android

Tags: java, android

Say I have a drawable id named R.drawable.example.

How do I write a function to get the name of the drawable from the id and vice versa? For example,

```
foo(r.drawable.example)
```

would return the String 'example', and

```
foo(example)
```

would return the int r.drawable.example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `getResources()` on a `Context` to get a `Resources` object. Then:

- [Call `getIdentifier()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to retrieve the numeric `R` value given the package, resource type (e.g., `"drawable"`), and resource name (e.g., `"example"`)
- [Call `getResourceName()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceName(int)) to retrieve the fully-qualified resource identifier (e.g., `"yourpackage:drawable/example"`) given the numeric `R` value